# SendKeys.SendWait does not send "{ENTER}" in Windows 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, sendkeys

I have tried this in Visual Studio 2008 with XP and Windows 7:

`SendKeys.SendWait("sometext{ENTER}{ENTER}")`

This is for opening a file in an open file dialog box. It works on XP with VS2008, but when I try on Windows 7, it seems that the {ENTER} keys are not going through.

Is there a known issue with this, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The reason this wasn't working is because Windows 7 was defaulting to not overwrite the file. Just needed to change it to "sometext{ENTER}{LEFT}{ENTER}".. thx though!

Answer (score 7):

this should work, you can try using \n as well:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("Hello World{ENTER}Testing\n");
```

This does work on my windows 7 machine. The problem you're having is most likely with the application you're attempting to send the keys to is running under a different privileged account (eg: as Administrator). This will prevent a user level application from sending the keys, unless you run your application as an Administrator as well. Try running Visual Studio as Administrator and testing your code again.

```
Right click Visual Studio -> Run As Administrator
```

Comment: thank you for this.  I have been stuck on this for 3 days because it didn't send the ENTER key to the active window at all until I follow your suggestion running the app as Admin.