# How do I programmatically press Enter?

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendkeys, enter

I have a C# console program which starts calculator and simulates key presses. How do I programmatically press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

```
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
        string lpWindowName);

    // Activate an application window.
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    // Send a series of key presses to the Calculator application. 
    private void StartCalculator()
    {
        Process.Start("calc.exe");
        IntPtr calculatorHandle = FindWindow("CalcFrame","Calculator");

        if (calculatorHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return;
        }

        SetForegroundWindow(calculatorHandle);
        SendKeys.SendWait("111");
        SendKeys.SendWait("*");
        SendKeys.SendWait("11");
        SendKeys.SendWait("=");
        SendKeys.SendWait(" ");//how press enter?
    }
```

Comment: For reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286086/sendkeys-sendwait-does-not-send-enter-in-windows-7

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Taken from [SendKeys.Send Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
SendKeys.SendWait("~"); // How to press enter?
```

or

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}"); // How to press enter?
```

Comment: I believe the documentation states that it's `"{ENTER}"` you need, not `"ENTER"`

Comment: @JasonEvans it uses {Enter} :)

Comment: You link to Send(), but tell us to use SendWait(). Why?

Comment: How can I do that with dotnet core console app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to relocate to a path then that time you need a dialog handle for that dialog box and use sendkeys like below:

```
`IntPtr dialogHandle = FindWindow("#32770", null);
if (dialogHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
string filepath = "path you wanted to relocate";
SendKeys.SendWait(Path.Combine(filePath,"{ENTER}"));
}`
```